# Mixpanel mock continuously comes back as undefined

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs, mixpanel

I have a very basic static app that has business logic to redirect a user based on what element they click in the UI. I added Mixpanel, and track an event before the user is redirected. I'm trying to create tests using the Jest testing framework, but am having difficulties mocking the track method invocation on mixpanel.

The crux of the issue is I'm unable to mock mixpanel while running tests. I've read the Jest documentation and searched the community for answers, but every time I run tests, it fails with ***TypeError: Cannot read property 'track' of undefined***. You'll have to forgive me if it is something obvious, JavaScript is not my native programming language, so when it comes time to build tests, I'm rusty at it. :)

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
  <!-- start Mixpanel -->
  <script type="text/javascript">...Mixpanel script</script>

  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    const { sources } = window.parseSourcesFromURL(window.location.href)
    const sourceObj = window.convertToObj(sources)
    mixpanel.track("Page View", sourceObj)
  </script>
  <!-- end Mixpanel -->
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="age-links">
      <button onClick=redirectFunc(true)>YES</button>
      <button onClick=redirectFunc(false)>NO</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**js/scripts.js**

```
(function() {
  const convertToObj = () => ...
  const getTrackingData = () => ...
  const parseSourcesFromURL = () => ...

  const redirectFunc = (p) => {
    const { sources, link1, link2 } = parseSourcesFromURL(window.location.href)
    const redirect = `${p ? link1 : link2}?${sources.join('&')}`

    const mixpanelTrackingData = getTrackingData(sources, p, redirect)

    mixpanel.track('Button Clicked', mixpanelTrackingData, () => {
      window.location.href = redirect;
    })
  }

  if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined')
    module.exports = {
      ....
    };
  else
    window.utmSourcesToObject = utmSourcesToObject;
    window.parseReferrerForLinksAndUTM = parseReferrerForLinksAndUTM;
    window.redirectBasedOnAge = redirectBasedOnAge;
})();
```

**js/scripts.test.js**

```
const { redirectFunc, parseSourcesFromURL } = require('./js/scripts')

const testURL = 'https://test.com/'

describe('parseReferrerForLinksAndUTM', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
      global.window = Object.create(window)

      Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
        value: { href: testURL },
        writable: true
      })

      ### THIS DOESNT WORK ###
      Object.defineProperty(window, 'mixpanel', {
        track: jest.fn()
      })
  })

  const { sources, link1, link2 } = parseSourcesFromURL(testURL)

  test('redirect link is correct', () => {
    ### THIS DOESNT WORK ###
    global.mixpanel = Object.create({})
    global.mixpanel.track = jest.fn()

    expect(link1).toBe('https://link1.com')
  })
})
```

Comment: Rather than a mock you could inject both dependencies to ease the test. We could imagine a function that takes the list of dependencies as argument and return the function scoped to those dependencies. It will ease the test but it will also be simpler to follow.

Comment: Thanks @SamuelVaillant, that is a good option and would make the functions I'm testing more deterministic. I'll move some things around.

Comment: @SamuelVaillant How do you do that exactly?